# RadioButton doesn't change after change orientation android

Tags: android, xml, orientation, landscape

I have a radioradio that I would like to modify the text when orientation changes

if orientation is landscape i would like just have drawable in the button and
if orientation is portrait i would like to have drawable and description

I have 2 xml (main_activty in layout and main_activity in layout_land)
this is code layout/main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Portrait"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Btn Portrait"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/btnControl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/zoom"
                     android:checked="true"
                     android:button="@null"
                     android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_plus"
                     android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                     android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                     android:gravity="center_vertical"
                     android:text="Zoom +"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/dim"
                     android:button="@null"
                     android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_minus"
                     android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                     android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                     android:gravity="center_vertical"
                     android:text="Zoom -"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

and layout-land/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Portrait"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Btn Portrait"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/btnControl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/zoom"
                     android:checked="true"
                     android:button="@null"
                     android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_plus"
                     android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                     android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                     android:gravity="center_vertical"
                     android:text="Zoom +"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/dim"
                     android:button="@null"
                     android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_minus"
                     android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                     android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                     android:gravity="center_vertical"
                     android:text="Zoom -"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

the difference between this 2 xml is the attribute text

the result when I run the app in portrait mode

[image]
[image]

the result when I run the app in landscape mode

[image]
[image]

when i change orientation nothing is happened with radiobutton and the other view change

I would like to do that without code java, is it possible ?

thank you in advance

Comment: Where is the code that switches from one Radio group to another? Both radio groups have the same id. I'm not sure how it would distinguish.

Comment: Both radio groups have the same id. do I have to add java code pour for I want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, all layouts in the `res/layout` folder are applied to both portrait and landscape versions.

What you need to do is for any layout that you would like to have a landscape alternative, you need to duplicate it and put it in the landscape folder like so:

If you have for example:

```
res/layout/main.xml
```

Then you will want to add another folder under `res` called `layout-land` which will act as the landscape version of all your `Activities`. Then you will want to move the landscape version of main.xml into the new folder.

You should end up with two versions of the file, portrait - res/layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/btnControl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/shutdown"
            style="@style/radioButton"
            android:text=""
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_shutdown"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

And landscape - res/layout-land/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/btnControl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/shutdown"
            style="@style/radioButton"
            android:text="Description button"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_shutdown"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Once you have launched the app and have both of these layout files and their folders implemented, as soon as an `Activity` flips to landscape then the layout will switch to the one in `res/layout-land`. Hope this helps and gives you a better understanding of how to implement landscape layouts.

Comment: I do that, but it doesn't work with radiobutton the other components (button, ...) change but not radiobutton :s

Comment: @JFouad Is it only the `android:text` that you want to change? Why do you need separate layouts for just that?

Comment: I changed the other components and now I need to modify radiobutton. I don't now why it doesn't change

Comment: How do you want to modify it?

Comment: I want just to delete de text and keep the drawable

Comment: You can do this without having to create a new layout file. Just modify it in code when landscape mode is active.